# why DbCommandBuilder (Oracle) produces weird WHERE-clause to UpdateCommand?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a table HolidayHome in oracle db which has unique db index on Id (I haven't specified this in the code in any way for adapter/table/dataset, don't know if i should/can).

DbDataAdapter.SelectCommand is like this:

```
SELECT Id, ExtId, Label, Location1, Location2, Location3, Location4, 
ClassId, X, Y, UseType 
FROM HolidayHome
```

but UpdateCommand generated by DbCommandBuilder has very weird where clause:

```
UPDATE HOLIDAYHOME SET ID = :p1, EXTID = :p2, LABEL = :p3, LOCATION1 = :p4, 
LOCATION2 = :p5, LOCATION3 = :p6, LOCATION4 = :p7, CLASSID = :p8, X = :p9, 
Y = :p10, USETYPE = :p11 
WHERE ((ID = :p12) AND ((:p13 = 1 AND EXTID IS NULL) OR (EXTID = :p14)) AND 
((:p15 = 1 AND LABEL IS NULL) OR (LABEL = :p16)) AND 
((:p17 = 1 AND LOCATION1 IS NULL) OR (LOCATION1 = :p18)) AND 
((:p19 = 1 AND LOCATION2 IS NULL) OR (LOCATION2 = :p20)) AND 
((:p21 = 1 AND LOCATION3 IS NULL) OR (LOCATION3 = :p22)) AND 
((:p23 = 1 AND LOCATION4 IS NULL) OR (LOCATION4 = :p24)) AND 
(CLASSID = :p25) AND (X = :p26) AND (Y = :p27) AND (USETYPE = :p28))
```

all these fields that have like:

```
((:p17 = 1 AND LOCATION1 IS NULL) OR (LOCATION1 = :p18))
```

are defined in oracle db like this:

```
LOCATION1 VARCHAR2(30)
```

so they allow null values.

the code looks like this:

```
        static bool CreateInsertUpdateDeleteCmds(DbDataAdapter dataAdapter)
        {
            DbCommandBuilder builder = _trgtProvFactory.CreateCommandBuilder();
            builder.DataAdapter = dataAdapter;

            // Get the insert, update and delete commands.
            dataAdapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();
            dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
            dataAdapter.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand();
        }
```

what to do? The UpdateCommand is utter madness.

Thanks & Best Regards: Matti

Answer (score 2):

I really don´t know the purpose of those ((:px = 1 AND XXX IS NULL) OR (XXX = :py)), but the CommandBuilder does generate a where clause to check if the row being updated has been changed since you loaded it. For example if you load a row R1 with values (c1, c2, c3,...,cn) and you change the value of c3 with c3' then the update command text has a where clause that checks for all the original values of the row (e.g. where C1 = c1 and C2 = c2 and ...). If the update command affects 0 rows it means that someone else has updated that row in the time between you loaded it and the time you updated it, and it throws a DbConcurrencyException. I know that you can change that behavior (don´t remember exactly how).

So that is the main reason of the Where clause in the update command.

Comment: yes. i know what A where-clause is. edit: personally i think answering 'I really don´t know the...' is not a good practice since now the question is not unanswered anymore.

Comment: The phrase "I really don´t know the purpose..." is because in this particular case, I don´t know what the column types are, if they are nullable, nor the parameter values. I didn´t explain what a where clause is, I told you why the DbCommandBuilder generates a where clause that may not appear as the typical where clause you write when you make an update.

Comment: you're right, but knew it already. anyway sorry about that. the thing i still do not know is this "((:p15 = 1 AND LABEL IS NULL) OR (LABEL = :p16))"-business. All these fields accept a null value.

edit: gave u an up-vote.

Comment: To disable column change WHERE conditions, you can use
`builder.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to how database NULLs are represented in your DataTable and how to test if the value of column in the database is still NULL

In SQL, NULL is not a value, it is a state.. so you can't test a sql column for NULL like this: `WHERE MyColumn = NULL`, this test will always return false

so you need two different test in your `WHERE` to check if actual column state is still the same.

The DataRows keeps both old and new values so the update command should be:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET KeyColumn = KeyDatacolumn.NewValue, OtherColumn = OtherDataColumn.NewValue
WHERE KeyColumn = KeyDatacolumn.OldValue AND OtherColumn = OtherDataColumn.OldValue
```

*Note that the WHERE condition on OtherColumn is needed only to avoid to overwrite someone else's updates to same record*

But, as said before, if OtherColumn is nullable, we can't simply test `WHERE OtherColumn = OtherDataColumn.OldValue`

so the update command will be:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET KeyColumn = KeyDatacolumn.Value, OtherColumn = OtherDataColumn.NewValue
WHERE
    (KeyColumn = KeyDatacolumn.OldValue) AND  
    (
        (OtherColumn = OtherDataColumn.OldValue)
        OR
        (
            (OtherDataColumn.OldValue.Equals(DBNull))
            AND
            (OtherColumn IS NULL)
        )
    )
```

You can read the condition on OtherColumn like "where OtherColumn has the same value it had before `OR` (it was NULL `AND` it is still NULL )"

So, for nullable columns will be used 2 different parameters for each column, the 1st one will be passed as `DataColumn.OldValue.Equals(DBNull)` and the 2nd one will be passed as `IIF(DataColumn.OldValue.Equals(DBNull), "NULL", DataColumn.OldValue)`

I hope to have been of any help
regards